# mysql data from several tables

Tags: mysql

I have an awkward mySQL query to make and I'm struggling due to a poor database structure (I made it years ago) :/

I have 3 tables, `forum_list`, `forum_topics` and `forum_replies`. I'm cycling through the forum_list table, showing the name, and I want to grab the date and author_id of the last post in each.

Problem is, the last post could be a reply in `forum_replies`, or it could be a topic `forum_topics`

Will I need a sub query or something?

---

Table `forum_list`

```
id     name    
1      General Chat
```

---

Table `forum_topics`

```
id    forum    author    date      
1     1        John      2012-12-12 12:12:12
```

---

Table `forum_replies`

```
id    forum    topic    author    date
1     1        1        John      2012-12-12 12:12:12
```

### update

```
SELECT     forum_list.id
,          GREATEST(forum_topics.date, forum_replies.date) date
,          CASE GREATEST(forum_topics.date, forum_replies.date)
           WHEN forum_topics.date THEN MAX(forum_topics.author)
           WHEN forum_replies.date THEN MAX(forum_replies.author)
       END author
FROM       forum_list
LEFT JOIN  (
       SELECT   forum_topics.id
       ,        max(forum_topics.date) date
       FROM     forum_topics
       GROUP BY forum_topics.forum
       )        forum_topics_max
ON         forum_list.id = forum_topics_max.id
LEFT JOIN  forum_topics
ON         forum_topics_max.id = forum_topics.id
AND        forum_topics_max.date     = forum_topics.date
LEFT JOIN  (
       SELECT   forum_replies.id
       ,        max(forum_replies.date) date
       FROM     forum_replies
       GROUP BY forum_replies.topic
       )        forum_replies_max
ON         forum_list.id = forum_replies_max.id
LEFT JOIN  forum_replies
ON         forum_replies_max.id = forum_replies.id
AND        forum_replies_max.date     = forum_replies.date
GROUP BY   forum_list.id
```

Comment: Could we see the table structures with the relevant fields (mainly the ids + foreign keys)?

Comment: done , its so messy but I have to work with it for now

Comment: does "date" actually hold a `DATETIME` value like `2012-12-12 12:12:12` and not a VARCHAR with the string `12/12/12` in it? I hope so .. ;)

Comment: There isn't quite enough information to answer this question. In particular, it is not clear whether it is guaranteed that there will be exactly one author in topics having date = max(date), same for replies. And even then, it is always possible that there is a topic as well as a reply, both having exact same max(date). So there has to be some rule that determines if you want to see a reply or a topic author in that case.

Comment: I'm not too concerned which it shows if 2 are posted on exactly the same milisecond, i doubt it'd ever happen on my site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
SELECT     forum_lists.forum_id
,          GREATEST(forum_topics.date, forum_replies.date) date
,          CASE GREATEST(forum_topics.date, forum_replies.date)
               WHEN forum_topics.date THEN MAX(forum_topics.author)
               WHEN forum_replies.date THEN MAX(forum_replies.author)
           END author
FROM       forum_lists
LEFT JOIN  (
           SELECT   forum_topics.forum_id
           ,        max(forum_topics.date) date
           FROM     forum_topics
           GROUP BY forum_lists.forum_id
           )        forum_topics_max
ON         forum_lists.forum_id = forum_topics_max.forum_id
LEFT JOIN  forum_topics
ON         forum_topics_max.forum_id = forum_topics.forum_id
AND        forum_topics_max.date     = forum_topics.date
LEFT JOIN  (
           SELECT   forum_replies.forum_id
           ,        max(forum_replies.date) date
           FROM     forum_replies
           GROUP BY forum_replies.forum_id
           )        forum_replies_max
ON         forum_lists.forum_id = forum_replies_max.forum_id
LEFT JOIN  forum_replies
ON         forum_replies_max.forum_id = forum_replies.forum_id
AND        forum_replies_max.date     = forum_replies.date
GROUP BY   forum_lists.forum_id
```

It looks complicated, but assuming forum_lists is not too big, I think this solution will be faster than Kaii's, especially as forum_replies and forum_topics grow larger.

Here's an alternative solution using correlated subqueries. They are generally slower than the solution above, but if forum_lists is very large (unlikely) then it might be faster:

```
SELECT     forum_lists.forum_id
,          GREATEST(forum_topics.date, forum_replies.date) date
,          CASE GREATEST(forum_topics.date, forum_replies.date)
               WHEN forum_topics.date THEN MAX(forum_topics.author)
               WHEN forum_replies.date THEN MAX(forum_replies.author)
           END author
FROM       forum_lists
LEFT JOIN  forum_topics
ON         forum_lists.forum_id = forum_topics.forum_id
AND        forum_topics.date = (
               SELECT MAX(date)
               FROM   forum_topics forum_topics_max
               WHERE  forum_topics_max.forum_id = forum_topics.forum_id
           )
LEFT JOIN  forum_replies
ON         forum_lists.forum_id = forum_replies.forum_id
AND        forum_replies.date = (
               SELECT MAX(date)
               FROM   forum_replies forum_replies_max
               WHERE  forum_replies_max.forum_id = forum_replies.forum_id
           )
GROUP BY   forum_lists.forum_id
```

Comment: I'll try it thanks. Is there any quick way to edit these queries all into one string lol? I have to do it to put in the PHP code, just wonderin if theres any tools.

Comment: @user1022585 Without an error message, I would have to guess what "not working" means. I assume you edited the query so the column names fit the actual column names as opposed to the ones I had to guess?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE author FROM forum_list LEFT JOIN ( SELECT forum_topics.' at line 6

Comment: Right. I see. It should not read END CASE author, just END author. Editing my answer.

Comment: Ive updated the question with the query im using (yours), its edited to fit my table. It returns all the forum_list entrys (just 5) but it doesnt return any dates or authors

Comment: That's because you wrongly substituted the column names. You (accidentally?) replaced .forum_id with .id. Going by the table data you posted, .forum_id from my original query should be replaced with .forum, so that it reads forum_lists.id = forum_topics_max.forum, and forum_lists.id = forum_replies_max.forum. And obviously, the SELECT of those subqueries on forum_replies and forum_topics should select the forum colum, not the id column.

Comment: kinda did. I laid down the basics but I needed more data pulled than I asked for, so I kinda gave up out of frustration. I'll do it another day.

Comment: Well, that's not cool! You should edit the question and do a better job of explaining what you want to do in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

This should get the answer, but it far from fast.

```
SELECT id, name, replies_1 .author, replies_1 .date
FROM forum_list
LEFT JOIN
(
    (SELECT forum, author, date FROM forum_topics)
    UNION
    (SELECT forum, author, date FROM forum_replies)
) AS replies_1 ON (replies_1.forum = forum_list.id)
LEFT JOIN
(
    (SELECT forum, author, date FROM forum_topics)
    UNION
    (SELECT forum, author, date FROM forum_replies)
) AS replies_2 ON (replies_2.forum = forum_list.id AND replies_2.date > replies_1.date)
WHERE replies_2.forum IS NULL;
```